# Alternative to @DirtyContext for isolated JUnit tests under spring boot with H2 in memory db

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

Right now I'm using `@DirtiesContext(classMode=DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)` in my JUnit-Testclasses, but I think this approach is way to overkill and also does add way more workload (and overhead) than needed, since the whole context will be recreated before each test case. The only thing I need out of the Annotation `@DirtiesContext` is that my in memory H2 database should be empty and recreated before each test method. Is there an easy way to automatically start each test case with a newly created and empty h2 Database?

PS: I think doing a `@Before` annotated method that clears the db by hand is not scaleable when the application will grow with over 100+ tables etc.

Current code example:

***Testclass***

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Slf4j
public class TestClass {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Check if X is saved in database")
    public void doXTest() {
        // do tests etc isolated 
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Do y")
    public void doYTestMethod() {
        // do test isolated with 
    }
}
```

***application.yml***

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:template-db
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: XXXXXXX
    password: XXXXXXX
    h2:
      console:
        enabled: true
        path: /h2-console
    jpa:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can annotate your test class with `@Transactional` and this will result that each test will run in a transaction that is rolled back after each test. This should leave the database tables in a clean test after each test and there shouldn't be a need to re-create the database for each test (as it's also rather expensive).

If you are using `@DataJpaTest` this already comes with the `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But isnt that abusive to the use of `@Transactional`?

Comment: I wouldn't say so as the `@DataJpaTest` annotations does the exact same thing

Comment: ok I've gone with `@Transactional` thank you for your help!